# Numpy Mean element wise over 3D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to take the mean of 9 arrays element wise so to have one

I need something fast. The first bit of code takes forever. And with numpy mean without specifying an axis I get one value. I dont want to specify an axis. I want to take the mean element by element.

with output: juneMean['wind'][:,:,:] how do I do this?

Comment: You don't need `[:, :, :]`. That just creates a view object into the entire array. In this case, the array itself will do fine, as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
june = [JunOne.variables['wind'], 
        JunTwo.variables['wind'],
        JunThree.variables['wind'],
        JunFour.variables['wind'],
        JunFive.variables['wind'],
        JunSix.variables['wind'],
        JunSeven.variables['wind'],
        JunEight.variables['wind'],
        JunNine.variables['wind']]

JuneMean = np.mean(np.array(june), axis=0)
```

Comment: I would have suggested `np.stack`, but it's functionally identical in this case